# Print a string range, extracting all columns

Tags: awk, sed, cut

I have a situation where I need to extract a string range from a .txt file.

There are 5 columns, and the string starting value is in column 3. Let's call it 201. Let's also call the end of the string range 251. However, I want to output all columns, not just column 3.

Therefore: input file -> extract all columns -> identify which line to print from based on what its start of range value in column 3 -> print everything from this value to the last value in the range -> output this range.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Thank you in advance!

**Example input data:**

```
#        col1        col2        col3        col4        col5
        42293       52029       25514      750014     6383844
        42293       52028       25514      750007     6383835
        42293       52027       25513      749999     6383825
...
        42293       51995       25497      749748     6383513
        42293       51994       25497      749740     6383504
        42293       51993       25496      749732     6383494
```

Comment: Can you provide example input and output data? It's important how the data is formatted.

Comment: Sure, here we go: [link](http://i70.photobucket.com/albums/i116/jcy1/columns_example_zps8i7kdbpf.jpg)

Comment: Please just edit a few lines of that into the question so that the question makes sense in the future (when the image link is expired). You want to select lines of that file where the value in col3 is greater than 200 and smaller than 251, correct? Or is it greater than 20100?

Comment: I'll bear that in mind for the future. Exactly - well, that was just a random example of a range for the sake of the question really.

Answer (score 1):

With awk you can simply say:

```
awk '$3 >= 201 && $3 <= 251' filename
```

`$3` stands for the value in the third column of the current line, and for lines that fulfill the condition, the default action (printing) is performed. If you also want to include the header, use

```
awk 'NR == 1 || ($3 >= 201 && $3 <= 251)' filename
```

`NR` is the current record number (by default also the current line number), so this will print the first line regardless of content.

Comment: That's brilliant - the second example you've given does exactly what I need, so thanks for that! One question though: what does the use of || mean, as compared to using one pipe?

Comment: It's the logical or operator (like `&&` is the logical and operator). That could use some parentheses, come to think of it -- operator precedence is not obvious between `||` and `&&`).